# Can i cast list to class after filtering on selected string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of a class called PlantAndPath (list1) which contains a group of objects of type PlantAndPath with a Plantname and a Path to the specific plant.

Then i have another list of strings (list2) which only contains a group of Plantnames.

I need to compare the Plantnames of these list and get a list of PlantAndPaths with the ones that only exists in list1.

So i use the .Except() method to filter out the ones i don't want. The problem is then when i filter on the Plantnames, i get a list of strings, and lose the path. I want a list of PlantAndPath.

```
        List<PlantnameAndPath> list1 = new List<PlantnameAndPath>
        {
            new PlantnameAndPath {Plantname = "Plantname1", Path = "Path1"},
            new PlantnameAndPath {Plantname = "Plantname2", Path = "Path2"},
            new PlantnameAndPath {Plantname = "Plantname3", Path = "Path3"},
            new PlantnameAndPath {Plantname = "Plantname4", Path = "Path4"}
        };

        List<string> list2 = new List<string>
        {
            "Plantname1",
            "Plantname2"
        };

        List<string> onlyInList1 = list1.Select(s => s.Plantname).Except(list2).ToList();

        List<string> whatIGet = new List<string>
        {
            "Plantname3",
            "Plantname4"
        };

        List<PlantnameAndPath> listOfWhatIWant = new List<PlantnameAndPath>
        {
            new PlantnameAndPath {Plantname = "Plantname3", Path = "Path3"},
            new PlantnameAndPath {Plantname = "Plantname4", Path = "Path4"},
        };
```

Comment: You're using a select which turns the `List<PlantnameAndPath>` into a `List<string>`. That's the reason why you're only getting the PlantNames. I'll add an answer to solve the issue when I have time.

Comment: list1.where(x=> !list2.contains(x.Plantname)).tolist();

Comment: as joeliius said, Select is the wrong method. You should use `.Where(s => !list2.Contains(s.Plantname))`

Comment: The thing is that both of the list might contain 150000 objects, and from my experience, the .Except() method is alot faster than to filter the way you did. Is it no way to do it with the .Except()  method?

Comment: @Brewsli - Create a `HashSet<string>` out of `list2` then you will get the speed of `Except` with the simplicity of Sebastian's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
List<PlantnameAndPath> onlyInList1 = list1.Where(s => !list2.Contains(s.Plantname)).ToList();
```

It takes all elements from `list1` `where` the `Plantname` is **not** included in the `list2`.

Other things that should return the same result but are not tested on performance:

```
// essentially making one list smaller by filtering first with except
List<string> wantedPlantNames = list1.Select(s => s.Plantname).Except(list2).ToList();
List<PlantnameAndPath> onlyInList1 = list1.Where(s => wantedPlantNames.Contains(s.Plantname)).ToList();
```

```
// use findAll function from list (no need to call .ToList which can be slow)
List<PlantnameAndPath> onlyInList1 = list1.FindAll(s => !list2.Contains(s.Plantname));
```

```
// use removeAll function from list. list1 will then only contain those you want.
list1.RemoveAll(s => list2.Contains(s.Plantname));
```

```
// using a hashset as @vyrp suggested in the comments
HashSet<string> badPlantnames = new HashSet<string>(list2);
List<PlantnameAndPath> onlyInList1 = list1.Where(s => !badPlantnames.Contains(s.Plantname)).ToList();
```

As you can see I sometimes took those which did fulfil a condition and sometimes those that didn't. With these different methods you should be able to compose something together which is fast enough for your use. You can easily mix these (eg. replace `Where().ToList()` with `FindAll()` in the HashSet-method) to try and get a better performance.

Let me know if you have results/news :)

Comment: The thing is that both of the list might contain 150000 objects, and from my experience, the .Except() method is alot faster than to filter the way you did. Is it no way to do it with the .Except()  method?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could of course use `Except` if you used your code which returns a list of Plantnames and then use `Where` to determine if the Plantname is in said list. This of course doesn't make any sense because you still have `Contains` and `Where`, so no I would say there is no way to do it with _only_ the `Except` method.

Comment: And the other way you could use `Except` would be to use new instances to compare against. Once again, really bad and doesn't make sense at all. So no, I can't think of a way.

Comment: Well now i tried with 110 000 in list1 and 150 000 in list 2. 

With your suggestion it took 14 minutes. 

With the .Except() method it took 3 minutes, and then i did like this to get my list with PlandnameAndPath: 

List<PlantnameAndPath> result = onlyInList1.Select(plantname => list1.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Plantname == plantname)).ToList();

Comment: For the performance concern, you could create a set: `var set = new HashSet<string>(list2);`, and use that set to do the check: `list1.Where(s => !set.Contains(s.Plantname))`. Let me know how long it takes.

Comment: @Brewsli the method you're using will probably yield wrong results if you have Objects with the same Plantname. The reason for that is that if the string "hello" gets picked by your select and is used to get the First element which has the Plantname "hello" then it can only get one or none (the first or none/default). This would also mean that you can only get as many objects with this method as you have Plantnames in your list which is faulty although it might work if you're lucky.

Comment: Thank you for your time Joelius, i will try this out as soon as i got time. And let you know the result :-)

Comment: So i ended up reducing the time from 14 minutes to 1 minute (150 000 in list1, 750 000 in list 2). So as you can understand, i'm very happy with that result. I used the Hashset variant. Thank you all so much!